# Heroku H12 (timeout) errors when loading Admin area of site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, timeout

We are having a timeout issue on Heroku with a site.  After accessing the admin area (/admin) it will hang and all users will receive H12 (request timeout) errors for about 2-3 minutes.  It seems like Heroku loads something and then continues.  Because everything works fine after this huge delay.

New Relic is not reporting large memory usage or anything else that is odd.  It does show that the request is queuing for the amount of time that it hangs.

This is a Rails 3.1.12 application.

The admin area is set up as a namespace:

```
## Admin Area
namespace :admin do
  match '/' => 'index#index', :via => :get

  ...
```

I realize that this is a very difficult issue to troubleshoot without access to the code.  Let me know if you have experienced this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're probably running only one dyno and only a single web process on that dyno.  You should look at using Unicorn or Puma or something to give you more web workers per dyno, and/or consider adding more dynos.